How would I test a next.js handler using vitest
I am new to testing and nextJs in general I am having trouble testing the following handler.
import axios from "axios";

const handler = (req, res) => {
    
    const { keywords } = req.body
    const URL = process.env.BASE + 'title';
    axios.post(URL, { keywords }, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        auth: {
            username: process.env.THEUSER,
            password: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
    }).then(response => {
         return res.status(200).json({ res: response.data.result_list, sessionId: response.data.session_id })}
    ).catch(error => { 
        return res.status(error.response.status).json({ res: error.response.data })
    })

}

export default handler;

The thing is i do not know how to approach the test because of the axios call.
I first tried mocking axios using vi.mock() it was a disaster i then tried to use msw but i am still stock. any guidance at this point would be greatly appreciated.
